# number of integers $n$ with $\|n \alpha \|$ small?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-approximation

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $N$ a positive integer. I am interested in the quantity
$$
D(\alpha, N) := \# \{ n \in [1, N]: \| n \alpha \| < 1/N  \},
$$
$\| x \|$ denotes the distance to the closest integer. Dirichlet's approximation theorem implies
$D(\alpha, N) \geq 1$ for all $N$. What I am interested knowing is does there exist $\alpha$ such that $D(\alpha, N) \leq C$ for all $N \geq 1$? Any reference is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: A relevant term to search for here is "badly approximable numbers".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. Assume that $\alpha$ is irrational, and its continued fraction digits do not exceed $K$. Then, for any positive integer $q$, we have
$$q\|q\alpha\|>1/(K+2).$$
In particular, for $q\leq N$, we have $\|q\alpha\|>1/(N(K+2))$. This implies that $D(\alpha,N)\leq 2K+4$, because one cannot accommodate $2K+5$ real numbers in $(-1/N,1/N)$ with pairwise distances exceeding $1/(N(K+2))$.